# How to make a horizontal scroll with the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to do a horizontal scroll while holding the mouse click, so as not to depend on the horizontal bar? And if possible, hide the bar?

That is, I want to imitate the same thing as the horizontal bar, but with the mouse.

Tried with JQuery's draggable () function, but I don't give it yet

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/n47kmjs6/

```css
#tab .tab-control {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.tab-control {
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#tab .tab-control li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
#tab .tab-control li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.tab-control li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.tab-control li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab-control">
  <li><a class="active" href="#tab-1">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-2">Oranges</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab-3">Fresh Meat</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-4">Vegetables</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-6">Fastfood</a></li>}
  <li><a href="#tab-7">Oranges</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab-8">Fresh Meat</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-9">Vegetables</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-10">Fastfood</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most browsers support horizontal scrolling by mouse wheel when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> button. It works fine even if left mouse button is being pressed.

About hiding scrollbar - use `margin-bottom: -17px; overflow-x: scroll;` for desktop browsers and place your element into some `div` with `overflow: hidden`.